# How to edit xml file using DOM in java (really different)

Tags: java, xml

I want to modify the following XML file :

```
<TVS>
  <Tv>
   <Detail>
   <Name>abcd</Name>
   <Model>yuio</Model>
   <InStock>20</InStock>
   <Price>6000</Price>
    <Description>nmk</Description>
   </Detail>
  </TV>
  <Tv>
    <Detail>
    <Name>bgtf</Name>
    <Model>wsxz</Model>
    <InStock>20</InStock>
    <Price>1000</Price>
    <Description>uhb</Description>
    </Detail>
  </TV>
</TVS>
```

the edited XML file should look like this:

```
<TV TotalValue="2354">
    <Detail Name="nmnm" Model="lkjh" InStock="12"/>
 </TV>
```

That means the attribute TotalValue should be generated and added to the  from 
  this  formula : 
TotalValue = Price * InStock and the Name and Model and InStock nodes   should be attributes for Detail

I have the following method for deleting elements :

```
private static void deleteElement(Document doc) {
    NodeList TV = doc.getElementsByTagName("Detail");
    Element emp = null;
    //loop for each 
    for(int i=0; i<TV.getLength();i++){
        emp = (Element) TV.item(i);
        Node DescriptionNode = emp.getElementsByTagName("Description").item(0);
        emp.removeChild(DescriptionNode);
    }

}
```

I need help for writing editElement method which is the hardest part!

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried with editElement() this far?

Comment: have u got the solution ?

Comment: no solution until now  !

Comment: ok m trying for the solution in this way parsing the xml and building new XMl .. u have to add one POJO to work with it... i am creating separate xml  file using above file..is it feasible for you?

Comment: thank you I need some time to test it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Detail.java

```
package com.sof.test;


public class Detail implements Comparable {

    private String Name;
    private String Model;
    private int InStock;
    private int price;

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return Model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        Model = model;
    }

    public int getInStock() {
        return InStock;
    }

    public void setInStock(int inStock) {
        InStock = inStock;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {

         if((((Detail)o).getInStock())*(((Detail)o).getPrice())  > (this.getInStock())*(this.getPrice())) 
         {

             return -1;
         }
        return 1;
    }

}
```

ReadXMLFile2.java

```
package com.sof.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Attr;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class ReadXMLFile2 {
    List<Detail> arrayList = new ArrayList<Detail>();

    public static void main(String argv[]) {

        try {

            File fXmlFile = new File(
                    "D:\\StackOverFlow\\DomParserTest\\src\\tvs.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            ReadXMLFile2 readXMLFile = new ReadXMLFile2();
            doc = readXMLFile.readNodes(doc);
            Document document = dBuilder.newDocument();

            readXMLFile.saveXml(readXMLFile.editXml(document));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Document editXml(Document document) throws Exception {

        Element roote = document.createElement("TVS");
        Element tvelement = null;

        Collections.sort(arrayList);


        for (Detail detail : arrayList) {

            tvelement = document.createElement("TV");

            Attr attr = document.createAttribute("TotalValue");

            attr.setValue("" + detail.getPrice() * detail.getInStock());
            tvelement.setAttributeNode(attr);

            Element det = document.createElement("Detail");
            attr = document.createAttribute("Name");

            attr.setValue(detail.getName());
            det.setAttributeNode(attr);
            attr = document.createAttribute("Model");

            attr.setValue(detail.getModel());
            det.setAttributeNode(attr);
            attr = document.createAttribute("Instock");

            attr.setValue("" + detail.getInStock());
            det.setAttributeNode(attr);

            tvelement.appendChild(det);

            roote.appendChild(tvelement);

        }
        document.appendChild(roote);

        return document;
    }

    public Document readNodes(Document doc) {

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Detail");

        Detail detail = null;
        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                detail = new Detail();

                detail.setName(eElement.getElementsByTagName("Name").item(0)
                        .getTextContent());
                detail.setModel(eElement.getElementsByTagName("Model").item(0)
                        .getTextContent());
                detail.setInStock(Integer.parseInt(eElement
                        .getElementsByTagName("InStock").item(0)
                        .getTextContent()));
                detail.setPrice(Integer
                        .parseInt(eElement.getElementsByTagName("Price")
                                .item(0).getTextContent()));

            }

            arrayList.add(detail);
        }
        return doc;
    }

    public void saveXml(Document doc) throws Exception {
        // write the content into xml file
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory
                .newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("file.xml"));
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        System.out.println("File saved!");
    }

}
```

I updated the answer with sorting based on "TotalValue". If you get this Accept it as answer ...

Comment: Thank you so much for the great job you have done ! It saved a lot of work and time for me ! I have one more question if I want to sort the elements on the TotalValue attribute(Descending) in the result XML file how should I modify the code?

Comment: dude not like dat.. u need click on the Right Mark beside my answer ...and click on up arrow mark den this question will shows as ANswered.